# Java function calls and declarations

Tags: java, function

I am new to java and writing code about adding numbers together writing private functions. I am getting errors on variables not resolved, errors on tokens, and missing constructs. I'm not exactly sure what is wrong.

```
import javax.swing.*;
    public class Note12FunctionExamples {
    int number1Integer = 0;
        int number2Integer = 0;
        int additionResultInteger = 0;
    
        number1Integer = 3;
        number2Integer = 4;
        
        
        additionResultInteger = addTwoNumbersAndReturnAdditionResult(number1Integer, number2Integer);
    outputMessageString = number1Integer + " + " + number2Integer + " is: " + additionResultInteger;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, outputMessageString);

private static int addTwoNumbersAndReturnAdditionResult(int number1Integer, int number2Integer) {
        int additionResultInteger = 0;

        additionResultInteger = number1Integer + number2Integer;

        return additionResultInteger;
    }
}
```

Comment: At a glance it looks like you're trying to write code outside of a method.  With the exception of fields and their (simple) initialization, code should be *in a method*.

Answer (score 0):

> *"... I am new to java and writing code about adding numbers together writing private functions. ..."*

It's worth noting, in *Java*, all *subroutines* are referred to as *"methods"*.
*[Defining Methods (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Classes and Objects)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)*.

Contrary to other languages which use the terms, *"functions"*, *"procedures"*, *"subroutines"*, etc.

> *"... I am getting errors on variables not resolved, errors on tokens, and missing constructs. ..."*

A *class* may only contain *"members"*.
*[Understanding Class Members (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Classes and Objects)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)*.

Meaning, variable re-assignment must be within a *method*, or a *[initialization-block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html)*.

Here is an example.
Additionally, you'll need to provide a *field* for, or *[declare](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)*, *outputMessageString*.

```java
void f() {
    number1Integer = 3;
    number2Integer = 4;


    additionResultInteger = addTwoNumbersAndReturnAdditionResult(number1Integer, number2Integer);
    outputMessageString = number1Integer + " + " + number2Integer + " is: " + additionResultInteger;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, outputMessageString);
}
```